# python tox - losing stuff on the way to the testing spot

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging, tox

this is my first time using tox to create a python package. I didn't underestimate this task and read myself a little bit into how setuptools and pyscaffold works, what does what and why and so on, got some yt-videos to grasp how to get it on.

But, guess what, it doesn't work, and i have absolutely no clue why.

This is what i did:

```
    putup --tox river
```

then i placed my sources under `src/`
and some tests under `tests/`

so this is my folder structure so far:

```
    river/
        src/
            dispatcher/
                __init__.py
                updater.py
            river/
                __init__.py
                dispatcher_config.py
                dispatcher.py
                flow.py
                logger.py
                log_config.yml
        tests/
            __init__.py
            test_cases.py
        AUTHORS.rst
        CHANGELOG.rst
        LICENSE.txt
        README.rst
        setup.cfg
        setup.py
        tox.ini
        log_config.yml
```

all i want to achieve for now is getting my tests running properly.

tox.ini :

```
    [tox]
    minversion = 2.4
    envlist = default

    [testenv]
    setenv = TOXINIDIR = {toxinidir}
    sitepackages = True
    commands =
        python --version
        pytest
    deps = pytest
```

setup.cfg - almost unchanged :

```
    # This file is used to configure your project.
    # Read more about the various options under:
    # http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#configuring-setup-using-setup-cfg-files

    [metadata]
    name = river
    description = Add a short description here!
    author = Kristian Jülfs
    author-email = kristian.juelfs@...
    license = mit
    long-description = file: README.rst
    long-description-content-type = text/x-rst; charset=UTF-8
    url = https://github.com/pyscaffold/pyscaffold/
    project-urls =
        Documentation = https://pyscaffold.org/
    # Change if running only on Windows, Mac or Linux (comma-separated)
    platforms = any
    # Add here all kinds of additional classifiers as defined under
    # https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers
    classifiers =
        Development Status :: 4 - Beta
        Programming Language :: Python

    [options]
    zip_safe = False
    packages = find:
    include_package_data = True
    package_dir =
        =src

    # DON'T CHANGE THE FOLLOWING LINE! IT WILL BE UPDATED BY PYSCAFFOLD!
    setup_requires = pyscaffold>=3.2a0,<3.3a0
    # Add here dependencies of your project (semicolon/line-separated), e.g.
    # install_requires = numpy; scipy
    # The usage of test_requires is discouraged, see `Dependency Management` docs
    # tests_require = pytest; pytest-cov
    # Require a specific Python version, e.g. Python 2.7 or >= 3.4
    # python_requires = >=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*

    [options.packages.find]
    where = src
    exclude =
        tests

    [options.extras_require]
    # Add here additional requirements for extra features, to install with:
    # `pip install river[PDF]` like:
    # PDF = ReportLab; RXP
    # Add here test requirements (semicolon/line-separated)
    testing =
        pytest
        pytest-cov
    #   flake8

    [options.entry_points]
    # Add here console scripts like:
    # console_scripts =
    #     script_name = river.module:function
    # For example:
    # console_scripts =
    #     fibonacci = river.skeleton:run
    # And any other entry points, for example:
    # pyscaffold.cli =
    #     awesome = pyscaffoldext.awesome.extension:AwesomeExtension

    [test]
    # py.test options when running `python setup.py test`
    #addopts = --verbose
    extras = True

    [aliases] 
    dists = bdist_wheel

    [bdist_wheel]
    # Use this option if your package is pure-python
    universal = 1

    [build_sphinx]
    source_dir = docs
    build_dir = build/sphinx

    [devpi:upload]
    # Options for the devpi: PyPI server and packaging tool
    # VCS export must be deactivated since we are using setuptools-scm
    no-vcs = 1
    formats = bdist_wheel

    [tool:pytest]
    addopts = --verbose
    norecursedirs =
        dist
        build
        .tox

    [flake8]
    # Some sane defaults for the code style checker flake8
    exclude =
        .tox
        build
        dist
        .eggs
        docs/conf.py

    [pyscaffold]
    # PyScaffold's parameters when the project was created.
    # This will be used when updating. Do not change!
    version = 3.2.1
    package = river
    extensions =
        tox
```

alrighti so far. Whatever i'm missing, i don't get it.

when i start tox on verbose,

```
    tox -r -vvv
```

i get this (cut)

```
    ...
      creating '/tmp/pip-wheel-rb7acy7z/river-0.0.post0.dev1+gc371b6b.dirty-py2.py3-none-any.whl' and adding '.' to it
      adding 'dispatcher/__init__.py'
      adding 'dispatcher/updater.py'
      adding 'river/__init__.py'
      adding 'river/dispatcher.py'
      adding 'river/dispatcher_config.py'
      adding 'river/flow.py'
      adding 'river/logger.py'
      adding 'river-0.0.post0.dev1+gc371b6b.dirty.dist-info/top_level.txt'
      adding 'river-0.0.post0.dev1+gc371b6b.dirty.dist-info/WHEEL'
      adding 'river-0.0.post0.dev1+gc371b6b.dirty.dist-info/METADATA'
      adding 'river-0.0.post0.dev1+gc371b6b.dirty.dist-info/RECORD'
      removing build/bdist.freebsd-12.0-RELEASE-p7-amd64/wheel
    done
      Stored in directory: /home/kjuelf/.cache/pip/wheels/f7/c7/76/923a5b579b9178351cdbe053f020f660101c03b78a4085d281
      Removing source in /tmp/pip-req-build-jhc29i8z

    Successfully built river
    Installing collected packages: river

    Successfully installed river-0.0.post0.dev1+gc371b6b.dirty

    Cleaning up...

    ...

    default start: run-test-pre 
    default run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='4259061550'
    default finish: run-test-pre  after 0.00 seconds
    default start: run-test 
    default run-test: commands[0] | python --version
    setting PATH=/usr/home/kjuelf/infra/river/.tox/default/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/kjuelf/bin
    [11307] /usr/home/kjuelf/infra/river$ /usr/home/kjuelf/infra/river/.tox/default/bin/python --version
    Python 3.6.9
    default run-test: commands[1] | pytest
    setting PATH=/usr/home/kjuelf/infra/river/.tox/default/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/kjuelf/bin
    WARNING: test command found but not installed in testenv
      cmd: /usr/local/bin/pytest
      env: /usr/home/kjuelf/infra/river/.tox/default
    Maybe you forgot to specify a dependency? See also the whitelist_externals envconfig setting.

    DEPRECATION WARNING: this will be an error in tox 4 and above!
    [11308] /usr/home/kjuelf/infra/river$ /usr/local/bin/pytest
    ============================================================ test session starts ============================================================
    platform freebsd12 -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-4.5.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0 -- /usr/local/bin/python3.6
    cachedir: .tox/default/.pytest_cache
    rootdir: /usr/home/kjuelf/infra/river, inifile: setup.cfg
    plugins: cov-2.7.1, flake8-1.0.4
    collected 0 items / 1 errors                                                                                                                

    ================================================================== ERRORS ===================================================================
    ___________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_cases.py ____________________________________________________
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:359: in get_provider
        module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]
    E   KeyError: 'river'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    src/river/logger.py:18: in <module>
        config = resource_string("river", "log_config.yml")
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:1156: in resource_string
        return get_provider(package_or_requirement).get_resource_string(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:361: in get_provider
        __import__(moduleOrReq)
    E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'river'

    ...
```

i mean, first

```
    Successfully built river
```

then

```
    E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'river'
```

in pkg_resources/__ init __.py - KeyError: 'river'

i can't get a clue whats wrong with pkg_resources here - where is my stuff gone suddenly o_0 ??!

I also don't get what that warning means:

```
    WARNING: test command found but not installed in testenv
```

it's there, pytest works, and the dependency is set in tox.ini

lost in weirdness

Comment: The line `sitepackages = True` seems dangerous. I would try without.

Comment: New Python packages should usually avoid unnecessary installation middleware like `setuptools` and `pyscaffold` – both of which are mostly obsolete in the post-Python 2.7 era. If you don't explicitly need either, you shouldn't. Instead of defining a `setup.py` file, simply declare a [PEP 517- and 518-compliant `pyproject.toml` file](https://snarky.ca/clarifying-pep-518) installable as is with [`poetry`](https://poetry.eustace.io). `poetry` makes Python packaging somewhat sane again. **tl;dr:** *Don't go down the `setuptools` blackhole of misery unless you absolutely must.*